# Google таблицы. Приватность

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Хотел бы поинтересоваться у местных знатоков. Как реализовать, что бы некоторые колонки и столбцы в листах были визуально доступны — только определенным пользователям? А остальные их просто не видели. Что-то наподобие ACL для столбцов.

Comment: Как-то может и можно, но это надо лезть очень глубоко в API. Я лично про функции идентификации пользователя не слышал.

Comment: Возможно тогда сделать видимым только для создателя документа?

Answer (score 0):

Полноценного ACL нет.
Если доступ к таблице предоставляется читателям и/или авторизованным редакторам (c/по email), можно скрыть столбцы/строки и установить защиту на них - чтоб редактировать мог только автор.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Снизим порог. Можно ли сделать, что бы колонка была видна только автору. Остальные не знали о ее существовании?